# BigQuery error in query operation : Invalid Crendentials

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to run bq from putty with simple select stmt from shell script to which it fails with saying "BigQuery error in query operation : Invalid Crendentials

Here is shell script file code

hw.sh -->

## !bin/bash

bq query select * from HUB.hub_test limit 1;

[Snap with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G10O.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Could you be missing the credentials or have them incorrect in your config?